# How to set NSDateFormatter to parse "..GMT+0000 (UTC)"

Tags: ios

A server is sending a date in this format: "Fri Dec 13 2013 16:26:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)" but I can't get it to parse using NSDateFormatter

If I do this this then it parses:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri Dec 13 2013 16:26:18"];
```

However I need this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss XXX"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri Dec 13 2013 16:26:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)"];
```

I've tried a few things for XXX such as z or Z but everything results in a nil date.

Comment: Look at the [formatting specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and use the proper timezone format to match what you have.

Comment: BTW - that date format is very unusual. Why have two timezone parts? You have both `GMT+0000` as well as `(UTC)`. What other values might you have? Will it always be UTC or will you have dates from other timezones?

Comment: I have no control over the server code sending the date, apparently it is supposed to be according to this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html.

Comment: There is nothing in that link that looks anything like that format.

Comment: I'll drop the server developers a bug report

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a date string with two separate timezone specifications is strange. It may work with:

```
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (z)
```

If the part in the parentheses will always be UTC then I would do:

```
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ '(UTC)'
```

or maybe:

```
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '(UTC)'
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one works, as does "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)"